# 16.04: How to Mirror Windows 10 in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, wireless, windows-8

I want to project my windows screen to ubuntu and want to use it as a second screen wirelessly. Is it possible to do so? Suggestions are highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Install a remote access client in Ubuntu, and link it over WiFi to a remote desktop server running on your Windows box.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Operating_system_support lists client and server apps by OS.

Both the client and server must run the same [remote access protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software#Remote_desktop_software).

Some folks find it easier to use the same app for both client and server (although not required).